# Is there a limit to the number of entries makeindex or xindy can process?

Tags: indexing, glossaries

I've been using the `etex` and `glossaries` packages, together with `pdflatex`, to build a document containing four main glossaries, each customised in a different way. So far the total number of occurrences of `\newglossaryentry` is 137. This number will keep increasing.

Is there a hard limit to the number of index entries that can be processed by the `makeindex` or `xindy` programs? Or rather, are there common issues plaguing such documents that experienced users can foresee?

(I'm not expecting an exhaustive answer, if one exists.)

Comment: How big do you plan to go? certainly a few thousand entries is no problem (I haven't checked whether the code has fixed limits)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The number is likely to increase at a rate of between 5 to 50 entries p/month over the next years, I'd say, although there's no exact science operating here. I changed my question slightly.

Comment: I tried with 10000 index entries, MakeIndex did 145735 comparisons for sorting them.

Comment: I can tell you, that a **single** index can be max. 1024 characters long in MakeIndex. I once observed this issue with `glossaries`. I do not know, whether there’s a similar limit for Xindy.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>CW from comments</sub>

An index with 10000 entries compiled successfully with MakeIndex doing 145735 comparisons during sorting.

There's a limit of 1024 characters for an index entry in MakeIndex (and possibly some length limit for Xindy).

Comment: is there a way to increase the limit of characters for an index entry? Should I modify any file MakeIndex is using?

Comment: @orestis21 Maybe it's possible to change the MakeIndex limit. But 1024 characters seem sufficient for most applications.